# PHP Notice: Array to string conversion in php file

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Need your help again.

Basically I would like to get a confirmation dialog if you would like to update records. If yes, call php function update_SQL to update them. I've written following piece of code in php:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        if(confirm('Records will be updated. Continue? ')) {
                <?php update_SQL($array); ?> //call php function here
        } else {
                return; //exit out of the file
        }
</script>";

function update_SQL($array) { //update records
}
```

The problem is as all records are in array, when I call the update_SQL function, it gives me following error:

FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in (FILENAME.php) on line" while reading response header from upstream

Can you please help??

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will need `ajax`. You can not call `php functions` from `JavaScript` this way..

Comment: This is not good practise to write PHP code inside JavaScript.

Comment: Why are you not trying it by using ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the previous person deleted his answer. He was correct.

The answer was to use it as following

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        if(confirm('Records will be updated. Continue? ')) {
                ".update_SQL($array)."
        } else {
                die;
        }
</script>";

function update_SQL($array) {
}
```

Comment: I can't really see how that solves your problem. you see: ALL php is executed before ANY javascript is executed. so in this case, `update_SQL($array)` is executed before your javascript is even sent to the browser. it is executed no matter what you do in the browser, you can echo JS from PHP, but for the server, it's just meaningless text. you *cannot* mix PHP and JS in that way, it just doesn't work.